# Subir imagen a MySQL desde Android Studio con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio

actualmente me encuentro trabajando en una función para mi app esta se trata de subir una imagen a mi base de datos desde Android Studio pero resulta que tengo un par de problemas con el resultado, me explico al momento de agregar la foto de la galería y darle al botón subir parece que no hay ningún problema cuando reviso mi servidor la imagen parece estar ahí pero su peso es de 0kb quiere decir que mientras se subía tubo alguna clase de error que no permitió que se subiera de manera correcta, aquí adjunto una imagen.
[image: Como pueden ver la imagen se sube correctamente incluso con su formato pero su peso es de 0kb]

El otro problema que tengo es que el nombre no se inserta en la base de datos nada mas la URL de la imagen como adjunto en esta otra imagen.[image: Como pueden ver el nombre no aparece solo la URL (que por este momento es inservible)]

Ahora sin mas aquí dejo mi código en el que he trabajado.

Este es el archivo PHP donde hago la consulta y la inserción a la base de datos

```
    <?php

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
 
    $nombre_categoria = $_GET['nombre_categoria'];
    $img_categoria= $_GET['img_categoria'];
 
    require 'conn.php';
 
    $sql ="SELECT id_categoria FROM categorias ORDER BY id_categoria ASC";
 
    $res = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
 
    $id = 0;
 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    $id = $row['id_categoria'];
    }
 
    $path = "images/$id.png";
 
    $actualpath = "https://pedidoslab.atspace.cc/images/$path";
 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO categorias (nombre_categoria, img_categoria) VALUES 
    ('$nombre_categoria','$actualpath')";
 
    if(mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql)){
    file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($img_categoria));
    echo "Categoría agregada correctamente!";
    }
 
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
   }else{
   echo "Error";
   }
```

Y esta es mi Activity donde tengo todo el código para hacerlo funcionar.

```
public class AgregarCategoria extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button btnBuscar, btnSubir;
private ImageView imageView;
private EditText editTextName;

Bitmap bitmap;
int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
String UPLOAD_URL = "http://pedidoslab.atspace.cc/upload.php";

String KEY_NOMBRE = "nombre_categoria";
String KEY_IMAGEN = "img_categoria";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.agregar_categoria);

    btnBuscar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBuscar);
    btnSubir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubir);

    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    imageView  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    btnBuscar.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSubir.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public String getStringImagen(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}

private void uploadImage(){
    //Mostrar el diálogo de progreso
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Subiendo...","Espere por favor...",false,false);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {
                    //Descartar el diálogo de progreso
                    loading.dismiss();
                    //Mostrando el mensaje de la respuesta
                    Toast.makeText(AgregarCategoria.this, s , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    //Descartar el diálogo de progreso
                    loading.dismiss();

                    //Showing toast
                    Toast.makeText(AgregarCategoria.this, volleyError.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            //Convertir bits a cadena
            String imagen = getStringImagen(bitmap);

            //Obtener el nombre de la imagen
            String nombre = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();

            //Creación de parámetros
            Map<String,String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();

            //Agregando de parámetros
            params.put(KEY_IMAGEN, imagen);
            params.put(KEY_NOMBRE, nombre);

            //Parámetros de retorno
            return params;
        }
    };

    //Creación de una cola de solicitudes
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Agregar solicitud a la cola
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Imagen"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            //Cómo obtener el mapa de bits de la Galería
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            //Configuración del mapa de bits en ImageView
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(v == btnBuscar){
        showFileChooser();
    }

    if(v == btnSubir){
        uploadImage();
    }
}
}
```

Y eso seria todo espero que alguien me pueda orientar sobre alguna posible solución o cambio en mis códigos de antemano muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola, parece que tienes un conflicto de conceptos. Directamente no puedes guardar una imagen en tu base de datos, a menos de que lo guardes en un formato blob o base64 que permita luego convertirlo a un formato de imagen válido con php. Lo que te recomiendo es que conviertas desde Java la imagen a base64 y eso lo recibas en tu server, con php luego lo conviertes  a imagen, la guardas y esa ruta la almacenas dentro de ese campo de tu BD y así tener acceso a esa imagen con cualquier navegador o pintarla incluso con Picasso en Android a través de la url generada por el paso anterior que te dije.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, pues esa parte que mencionas ya esta en mi clase java amigo justo en esta parte del código convierto la imagen a base64 `public String getStringImagen(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}`